# how to set text to a jcombobox, but the text set should not be an element of jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

is their any way to set text for a combo box, which is not an element of the combobox.

```
cboSubjects=new JComboBox();
cbo.addItem("Maths"); // and few more subjects are added
cbo.setSelectedItem("subjects"); // this does not set the default text of combobox
```

Is their any way to solve this problem ? I need something which works like combobox.text 
property of combobox in visual basic

I am working on school management system. I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to show you a possible alternative :)

[image]

Note, you need to call `label.setDisplayedMnemonic('s');` and `label.setLabelFor(combo)` to complete the effect!

Comment: if that is the answer, I didn't understand the question at all ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra then you should probably comment on the question :P :P

Answer (score 1):

You can make jComboBox editable, `cbo.setEditable(true);`, and after that set the text you want: `cbo.setSelectedItem("subjects")`;